# What's the typeface used in The Zero Theorem film?

Tags: font-identification

Anyone recognize these fonts? I don't quite agree with what I'm getting from WhatTheFont.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: And what are you getting from What The Font?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I did a couple of tries but none of them matched: [Here](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=A&ch%5B1%5D=S&ch%5B2%5D=I&ch%5B3%5D=%CE%B1&ch%5B4%5D=%26&ch%5B5%5D=E&ch%5B6%5D=U&ch%5B7%5D=R&ch%5B8%5D=%CE%A9&ch%5B9%5D=P&ch%5B10%5D=E&wtfserver=wtf_b_41&id=002633cc5498115e000c19ca000005cd&glyphcount=11&imageid=0&x=62&y=36). The other one's url is too long but it gave me 3 results: Identical Sans Light, Red Ring Light and District Book.

Comment: The odd E, A, and O are most likely normal Greek and Cyrillic capitals and not part of the Latin set of the font. Can you crop off the excessive black?

Comment: @user42801 You can't use myfonts search URLs: they expire.

Comment: @AndrewLeach huh. You're right. I tried viisiitiing it using a private browser though so I thought it should work.

Comment: @Jongware iThat's what I tried with my first try. It included the Alpha and omega letters. Then on my second try, the sigma and delta. No joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it might be a [custom typeface](http://www.brandtanim.co.uk/carousel/ZeroTheorem.html) Brandt Animation made for the movie's title sequence.

The closest I could find was Alleyn typeface by Aviation Partners, but it doesn't seem to include Greek letters.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. I did end up on that page and I thought whatever it was would be out there.